# How to add/enable a new vNIC interface on linux

Tags: networking, ip-address, network-interface, ifconfig

I want to configure vNIC interface (ens37) with a manual IP address - 192.168.16.1/24 on linux box 
Currently I see **ens33** configured. So this is another interface I want to manually add.
Any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: What will the new interface be connected to? Physical Ethernet? Nothing?

Comment: ens37 is connected to a host-only private virtual network

Comment: two virtual NIC (vNIC) interfaces (ens33 and ens37).
The Linux server should have both vNIC interfaces enabled. ens33 allows
connection to the Internet through NAT whereas ens37 is connected to a
host-only private virtual network, which both Linux systems connect to

Comment: Ah, so it's a virtual machine where you've already added the "physical" interface through the VM?